# SQL sum of rows

Tags: sql, select

I have 300 records in my database and my structure is something like this

```
State                      values
Queensland                 4554
Queensland                 2343
Queensland                 9890
NSW                        1333
```

I want to retrieve all the records with state name `Queensland` and I want to sum all the records with field name values and the sum to be divided with the number of records (count) with state name.

Can anybody help me out with the syntax to achieve this?

I need something the output to be 5595.66 (i.e. (4454+2343+9890)/3)

Comment: In short, you want an average of the values column of the records with state name Queensland, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT State, SUM(values) / (COUNT(*) * 1.0)
FROM   tableName
WHERE  State = 'Queensland'
GROUP  BY State
```

OR

```
SELECT State, AVG(values * 1.0)
FROM   tableName
WHERE  State = 'Queensland'
GROUP  BY State
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a81a5/7)

As a sidenote, the columnName `values` is a Reserved keyword. Escape it by a delimiter depending on the RDBMS you are using. Like (*backtick*) MySQL, (*brackets*) SQL Server, etc....

Answer (score 1):

Based on

> "I want to **retrieve all the records** with state name "Queensland".."

Are you looking for this (for SQL-Server) ? [Fiddle-Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3069c/22)

```
select [state], round(avg(value *1.0) over() ,2) avgValue
from T
where [state] ='Queensland'

--Results
state       avgValue
Queensland  5595.67
Queensland  5595.67
Queensland  5595.67
```